# Show categories in tablayout and select tab with categorie id

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-tabs

I receive categories data from server in Json using retrofit and save in array `catlist`. each category has a `CategoryID` and `CategoryName`.
i want to use tablayout to show all of categories(not much) and with selecting tabs , use `CategoryID` to get items with this id from server and show in recyclerview. i don't know how do this .

Comment: Please show some codes you have tried so far.

Comment: @Tepits Unfortunately i have not been able to make a dynamic tablayout and this is problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34308112/6891563 Does this help you

Comment: @Khemraj not really

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately i get the answer! this link helped me to have a dynamic `tablayout`:
[Github link](https://github.com/dhirajaknurwar/dynamicFragmentTablayout/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/master/tablayoutwithdynamicfragments)