# recyclerview of recyclerviews with title

Tags: android, mobile

how can i make a RecyclerView of Recycler Views with a superior title in such a way that, when i scroll the screen down, the superior title of this category gets selected.At the same time,i have the possibility of clicking at some title and go to its position of list

[First image showing first collection of items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfGQH.png)

[Second image showing that another title was selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKzJv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `RecyclerView` of a `RecyclerView` is probably not what you require, instead, what you need is probably a `TabLayout` where the tabs contain `RecyclerView`. Here's a nice [codelabs example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/material-design-style/index.html?index=..%2F..io2016#0) to get you started. You can also create a new Tabbed `Activity` directly using Android Studio, that'll fill in a lot of the boilerplate code.

Now, if you're absolutely sure that you actually need a `RecyclerView` containing `RecyclerView` (I suppose, if you have a list of tabs whose actual values you don't know or which might change and they have properties that allow you to design them as `RecyclerView` of `Tabs`), then check out [RecyclerTabLayout](https://github.com/nshmura/RecyclerTabLayout).

Comment: You can use the tab layout for the horizontal items. But if you want a list with items and category titles in the same list you can use an RecyclerView Adapter with multiple view holders, each one extending a base view holder. So you add in the list the titles as well and you will use the view holder for that type of item.

Comment: Yes, I get that there are use-cases/scenarios where you might actually want to do that, to hopefully make your work simpler. But mostly, you know exactly what tabs are required. And [dynamically adding/removing tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306476/dynamically-add-and-remove-tabs-in-tablayoutmaterial-design-android) using `TabLayout` is really simple anyway.

Comment: The only legit reason (IMO) to use a `RecyclerView` in place of a `TabLayout` is when you have infinite tabs or an extremely large number of tabs.